error when trying to move SharePoint 2019 site to new content database
What am i doing wrong?  I am brand new to SharePoint so please be patient with me.  I have created the content database.  I get this error
PS C:\Users\spadmin> Move-SPSite "https://sharepoint.server.com/sites/sma-acct" -DestinationDatabase "SP_Accounting"

Confirm Are you sure you want to perform this action? Performing the
operation "Move-SPSite" on target
"https://sharepoint.server.com/sites/sma-acct". [Y] Yes [A] Yes to All
[N] No [L] No to All [S] Suspend [?] Help (default is "Y"): y

****Move-SPSite : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: v1 At line:1 char:1
Move-SPSite "https://sharepoint.server.com/sites/sma-acct" -Destinati 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveSite:SPCmdletMoveSite) [Move-SPSite],
Argu mentNullException
  FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveSite**** 


WARNING: IIS must be restarted before this change will take effect. To
restart IIS, open a command prompt window and type iisreset.

Please make sure that the name of the destination content database is correct and matches the name you provided in the PowerShell command. Also, ensure that you have the necessary permissions to perform this operation.
For your reference:
Move site collections between databases in SharePoint Server

Sorry but how did you create the new content database? I hope it was created by PowerShell command New-SPContentDatabase command.
Next, you can check if the source and destination databases are not in Read-Only state.
